# Google app engine - updating data from backend

Tags: google-app-engine, ide, backend

**What is the best way to UPDATE records in google app engine's Big Table through backend?**

I have google app engine application where users sign up and perform a bunch of activities. Now, I have added a new feature to award POINTS to the user based on the activity. For the point system to be accurate, I need to manually calculate the points for activities completed in the past(I have stats to do that) & UPDATE the big table by using queries. So what is the recommended way to do this?

*I am looking for some kind of IDE-like interface/command-line tool to get this done.*

Some clarifications:

- I am NOT looking for bulk upload of data. Data is already there. I just got to UPDATE it.
- I know I can do this by writing a java/python
  program, but I am trying to update using queries alone.
- I cannot delete and re-create data

Possible?

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations ('appln') in SO questions.

Comment: Also, what do backends have to do with the question?

Comment: By backend, I meant that I need to directly write to the backend BigTable using GQL instead of writing code to write to accomplish it

Comment: It's called the "datastore". Backends are a completely different concept in App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no 'update' queries in App Engine, and I'm not aware of any tools that implement them in an administrator interface. You will have to fetch, update, and write each record using code.

Comment: Ah.. thats what I thought too. But.. I heard that there is a python command line tool that kind of simulates update queries. Internally, it does fetch, update, write. But it supposedly abstracts those operations. I was wondering if there is a tool of that sort & if anyone here have used it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Ravi You might be thinking of `remote_api` and the `remote_api_shell`, but that doesn't abstract anything - it just provides an interactive console with which you can manipulate your data.